# Algolia : How to filter out a list of objectIDs client side

Tags: algolia

I have a list of users a user can follow, coming from the algolia index.

```
const index = client.initIndex('index');

const f= { filters: 'objectType:user };

index.search('user', f, (e, c) => {
       const x = c.hits;
});
```

Now, there's an array of user IDs of users this user is already following, I don't want those users to be returned from this search, how do I filter those out. `UserID` is `objectID` in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using Algolia's "Negative Filters" do achieve that.

https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/searching/filtering/?language=instantsearchjs#negative-filters

So if you have an array of user ids, you could build a filter that looks like:

```
const filters = 'objectType:user AND NOT objectID:123 AND NOT objectID:456 ...';
```

You could build this filter string by looping through you array of ids, and adding this to your filter for each user id:

```
`AND NOT objectID:${userId}`
```

Comment: Considering that the list of IDs might get to thousands, this is a weird solution, but let me try that.

Comment: Is this still applicable?